# Looping AngularJs for GET last data json form API webservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, controller

I wrote this code for get last array data json on my API, everytime data json always have new array. How to execute this code GET from my API everytime?

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('GempaTerbaruController', function($scope, services, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $cordovaNetwork) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Jaringan Terputus',
            template: 'Tidak dapat dimuat, Hubungkan dengan Internet'
          })
          .then(function(res) {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
          })
    }
})

$ionicLoading.show({
  template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
  });

$scope.dataGempa = {};

function getGempa() {

  services.getGempa().success(function(data) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.dataGempa = data.data.pop();

    console.log(data.data);
          });
}

getGempa();
```

Comment: I think you want the last item from an array which is getting from the API isn't it

Comment: yes, i want the last item. how can I execute http.get to get last item everytime?

Comment: If you want to get only last item you need to do it on server Side

Comment: If you want to do it in the client side try
and if the data.data is an array
$scope.dataGempa = data.data[data.data.length - 1];

Comment: I've managed to retrieve data from the server but if there is new data, the application can not display the new data. When I close the app and open it again, I can display the last data. I think that GET method only runs 1 time every I open the app.

Comment: Yes getGempa() is calling only once i think you need to call getGempa () when ever needed